# How do I get this database interaction working? I keep trying and it keeps throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I'm a student. Don't worry, my lack of skills are currently not a detriment to any professional organization.

I'm trying to set up a password system based on a database right now. There's a lot of elements to go, but right now I just want to call some data and insert it into my project.

Currently I'm getting NullReferenceException at  if (dr.Read())

The relevent code would be:

```
       string strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=access.mdb";
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    DataTable dt;
```

and

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select PASSWORD from regulate where NAME = @ID", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtName.Text);
                conn.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch
            { }
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                txtVaries.Text = dr["PASSWORD"].ToString();
            }
            conn.Close();

            if (txtVaries.Text == txtPW.Text)
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPW);
                tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabMain);
                tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tabEdit);
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not in the line that you tell us, but before and it is caused by your attempt to use the `SqlClient` classes to connect to an `MS-Access` database. For Access you need to use `OleDb` not SqlClient. The error is hidden by your empty try catch block. Never use empty catch block unless for really trivial situations that could be recovered without impacting in any way the works of your program.

```
string strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=access.mdb";
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

    using(OLeDbConnection = conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnectionString))
    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select [PASSWORD] from regulate where NAME = @ID", conn);
    {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtName.Text);
            conn.Open();
            using(OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                 ......... read your data .....
            }
     }
 }
```

Notice that I have put the word PASSWORD inside square brackets, PASSWORD is a reserved keyword in Access and you need to disambiguate it when you use it in sql command texts

Another thing to look at is the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). In this way your connection, command and reader are disposed and the resources they use are released at the closing brace of the using block. This closes also the connection and the reader ALSO in case of exceptions simplyfing your code a lot.

As noted in comment below from [Mr. Damith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558060/damith) a query that returns just one column from one row could be executed using `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`. The ExecuteScalar is better for performances because it doesn't construct an OleDbDataReader object that keeps the connection busy and open until the close. It just returns the single value requested but you need to ba prudent because, if the query doesn't find any user matching the where clause, the return value will be null

```
....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtName.Text);
conn.Open();
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
    txtVaries.Text = result.ToString();
else
    MessageBox.Show("No user found!");
```

Comment: This is more a comment

Comment: It's not a comment. This is the solution to the question. Because that is the only way the `dr` can be `null`, because the OP is *eating* the exception in the empty `catch` block.

Comment: 1+ This is the solution for the main issue in the given code

Comment: @Shiva the solution of a problem contains code. Anyway Steve is correct and I upvote him, but he should add some code.

Comment: That still does not make it a comment. It makes it an incomplete answer.

Comment: I started with OleDb, but couldn't figure out how to format a parameter properly, and didn't want to leave myself open to a SQL injection attack. Can I make a parameter like cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtName.Text); but in a format that would work with the OleDb formatting?

Comment: @AarronDixon yes, usually OleDb want the parameter placeholders in the form of a question mark without name. But Access accepts also the form `@xxxx` as Sql Server or MySql. Probably to ease portability. However OleDb doesn't recnognize such names. You should put the parameters inside the collection in the same order in which the placeholders appears in the command text

Comment: @Steve OP need only the password value, i think just `ExecuteScalar` will do the job

Comment: @Damith yes that's is another advice to give here.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the correct ADO provider. I did not notice that at first, was more concerned with the overall problems in the approach.

Comment: I couldn't get the exact code above to work, but it lead me to a workable solution. I'll mark this as the correct answer, but also post the code I ended up on.

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason for your error is answered by @Steve with use of OleDb connection string in SqlClient. I want to point out an overall approach. Regardless of which of the ADO provider you use one issue is your empty catch block is an exception pac-man, it eats any errors without reporting them or rethrowing.

Then, the preconditions for dr.Read() may not have been met, but you still call dr.Read() even if connection throws an exception. You could have a null reader at that line.

Lets assume your user types in the cleartext password, then you should hash it, and compare to the 1-way hash in the database.

Instead the general structure of code should be:

```
try {
   using(var conn = new OleDbConnection(...)) {
      using(var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ...", conn)) {
         conn.Open();
         using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader(...)) {
            if(reader.Read()) {
               var user = new User {
                  Id = reader.GetInt32(0), PasswordHash = reader.GetString(1)
               };
               if(User.SHA2Hash(loginPass) == user.PasswordHash)
                  return user;
               else
                  return null;  // or throw security exception
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
catch(Exception ex) {
   Logger.Error(ex);  // REPORT ERROR! DONT EAT IT
   throw new SecurityException("Login exception", ex);
}
```

The important idea is to use using blocks for the IDisposable resources to be properly disposed upon failure or success.

Note you can simplify if you write your query such that it will return a single value, though I never do for Login code, usually I return a user record with various fields, using reader. If you know your query will return 1 row/col, ExecuteScalar() is better since ExecuteReader() alocates a needless IDisposable resource.

Comment: I hadn't gotten to that security aspect of it yet, but I'm heading there fast. The information on hashing could come in quite handy very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Steve's advice lead me to the following solution:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
e.Handled = true;
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

string strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=access.mdb";
     string strCommand = "SELECT PASSWORD FROM regulate where NAME=@ID";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(strCommand, conn);
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtName.Text);
conn.Open();
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        { 
            txtVaries.Text = dr["PASSWORD"].ToString();

        }
        conn.Close();

            if (txtVaries.Text == txtPW.Text)
            {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPW);
                tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabMain);
                tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tabEdit);
            }
        }
```